# How to call class first without call modal if it meets certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

Demo and Full Code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/xzxrp7nn/2/

My HTML Code is like this :

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg check_session" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="idTourDateDetails">Tour Start Date:</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
$(".check_session").click(function(){
        $.ajax({ 
            success : function(response)
            {
                response = 'no_session';
                if(response != 'exist_session')
                {
                    alert('Please login');
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

When `response != 'exist_session'`, I want the system display alert message without display modal. So only display alert message.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove data-toggle and data-target in button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg check_session">Launch demo modal</button>
```

then you can call it in javascript.

```
$(".check_session").click(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        success : function(response)
        {
            response = 'no_session';
            if(response != 'exist_session')
            {
                alert('Please login');
            } else {
                $('#myModal').modal()  
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Working Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/xzxrp7nn/4/